# Disabling -Werror argument in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Log:

```
    Kotlin: kotlinc-jvm 1.5.10-release-891 (JRE 11.0.2+9)
    Kotlin: Language version 1.3 is deprecated and its support will be removed in a future version of Kotlin
    Kotlin: warnings found and -Werror specified
```

I tried to remove the argument from pom.xml, and that doesn't work. where else I can check to disable this flag?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiler-kotlin-compiler.html

Comment: File -> Project Stucture -> Project Settings -> Facets -> Additional command line parameters.

Here I had the -Werror argument and removed it, after that it worked.
Thanks DaveNewton , @CrazyCoder for your responses.